# Can i create a react component without ts like this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import * as react from 'react'
import { propsModel } from '...'
...
...

class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, propsModel> {
  render () {
    ....
  }
}
```

can create component like this ? why i did't see this way on [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/) and use this way cant `export default`,  but `export` fine

Comment: You need to clarify a bit more, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: `export class MyComponent ....` it worked, `export default class MyComponent ...` didn't work,  and also i don't know what is`<any,  propsModel>`, generally create a component ` class MyComponent extend React.Component {}` ,

Comment: <any, propsmodel> is typescript specific syntax for indicating types for generic classes and functions. If you remove that it should work on a .js file. Usually react is imported as import React from 'react'.